# Cisco WDS, FreeRadius and LEAP

Tags: cisco, wireless, radius

Freeradius got rid of LEAP since some pointrelease of 3.2.x, and I'm stuck configuring Cisco WDS on their Aironet series.

Since forever there was a tweak with LEAP in Cisco configuration like this:

```
eap profile leap
 method leap
!
wlccp ap username office-ap1 password 0 XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
wlccp ap wds ip address 192.168.31.41
wlccp ap eap profile leap
!
```

which allowed the access point to get registered with WDS master. Without leap they would merely get stuck forever in **AUTHENTICATED** state instead of **REGISTERED**. The LEAP tweak was shown for me by the Cisco TAC. Now when LEAP is gone from FreeRadius I'm back to **AUTHENTICATED** state.

Does anyone have a working example of WDS configuration with FreeRadius ? Ive tried several approaches like

```
eap profile md5
 method md5
!         
eap profile default
 method gtc
!
wlccp ap eap profile default
```

but none seems to be working.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question on [sf].